Do you have to double a out of turn bet out of turn
Here is the situation: Player 2 bet 16000 out of turn. Player 1 object to this and want to bet 20000.
Does player one has to double the raise of player 2 or he is in his right to bet the amount that he wants

Player 1 can't be penalised by player 2's out of turn action, therefore player 1 has all options open as if player 2 hadn't done anything.
The standard penalty for player 2 is that he gets his 16000 back but may now only call or fold to the 20000 and can't raise at all on this round (or street) of betting. Player 2 gets a warning for acting out of turn and giving prior players free information and players are advised to keep their cards visible so everyone knows when the action is on them.
